# Constant value in Verilog

Tags: verilog, constants, system-verilog, compile-time-constant

How to define a constant value for addition in verilog,

for example if I define a value `A=64'h000000000000001;`

use it later for addition how should I define in verilog.

Answer (score 2):

In SystemVerilog, it's reccomended that you put all constants in a global package, and import the package where needed

```
package globals;

  parameter A=64'h000000000000001;

endpackage
```

Comment: Is it synthesisable and can I assign in this way .in any array a[0] ,a[1]...........

Comment: Yes, it's synthesizable. You must initialize a parameter is a single assignment, but the right hand side can be a concatenation to separate individual elements. `parameter bit [63:0] A = {1'b1, 1'b0, ... );`